# git push/pull - default to github

Tags: git

I messed some config files up and need to get so that my git repos will push pull by default to master on github. I get this message the below code as a hint on what to fix and i understand it except for the `<refspec>` under `[remote "<nickname>"]` what goes here?

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = <nickname>
    merge = <remote-ref>

[remote "<nickname>"]
    url = <url>
    fetch = <refspec>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@github.com:<user_name>/<repo_name>.git

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```